# How do I write SELECT FROM myTable WHERE id IN (SELECT...) in Linq?

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

How do you rewrite this in Linq?

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM TableA WHERE TableA.Id IN (SELECT xx from TableB INNER JOIN Table C....)
```

So in plain english, I want to select Id and Name from TableA where TableA's Id is in a result set from a second query.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
from a in TableA 
where (from b in TableB 
       join c in TableC on b.id equals c.id
       where .. select b.id)
.Contains(a.Id) 
select new { a.Id, a.Name }
```

Answer (score 4):

LINQ supports IN in the form of contains.  Think "collection.Contains(id)" instead of "id IN (collection)".

```
from a in TableA
where (
    from b in TableB
    join c in TableC
        on b.id equals c.id
    select b.id
).Contains(TableA.Id)
select new { a.Id, a.Name }
```

See also this blog [post](http://blog.wekeroad.com/2008/02/27/creating-in-queries-with-linq-to-sql/).

Answer (score 1):

There is no out of box support for IN in LINQ. You need to join 2 queries.