# How do I write SELECT FROM myTable WHERE id = (SELECT) in Linq?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda

How can I rewrite this SQL query in LINQ with a lambda expression?

```
SELECT 
    CO.* 
FROM 
    COMPANY CO 
WHERE 
    CO.ID = '5' 
    AND CO.ID <> (SELECT COMPANY_ID 
                  FROM dbo.EMPLOYEE 
                  WHERE USERNAME = 'ADMIN')
```

I tried the following code I think it is correct, but it is not working:

```
var obj1 = db.COMPANies
             .Where(co =>  co.ID != co.EMPLOYEEs.SingleOrDefault(em => em.USERNAME == userName).COMPANY_ID && co.ID == iID);
```

Can you please help me?

Can I use

```
co.EMPLOYEEs.SingleOrDefault(em => em.USERNAME == userName).COMPANY_ID
```

inside the `db.COMPANies.Where`  ??

I have read the question in: [How do I write SELECT FROM myTable WHERE id = (SELECT) in Linq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45634/how-do-i-write-select-from-mytable-where-id-in-select-in-linq)
but it not help me.

EDIT : 
[Image table structure, Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zU9mg.png)

Sorry for my bad english. Thanks!

Comment: Can you share your table structure? I think you have some sort of foreign relationship between the company and employee table. Joining by `USERNAME` seems like a bad practice. Adding a normal relationship between the tables might simplify your current problem.

Comment: Yepp. refresh page, please. i don't know add image in here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope that you have **objects** of `COMPANY` table and `EMPLOYEE` table which will be having the data. On those objects, you can fire the below LINQ to achieve your results.

```
COMPANY.Select(x => x.Id == 5 && x.Id != EMPLOYEE.Where(z => z.USERNAME == "ADMIN").Select(g => g.COMPANY_ID).FirstOrDefault());
```

Don't forget to add `using System.Linq;`

Comment: Yepp .it working . thank you . i can understand your idea :D . However, we can use x.EMPLOYEE.Where inside COMPANY.Select ( x => ) ?? because I see EMPLOYEE can be called from x ? thanks for the good feedback

Answer (score 1):

Using lambda expression, you can try this

```
var comapaniesWhereUserIsAdmin = from e in db.EMPLOYEEs
                                 where e.username='Admin'
                                 select e.CompanyId;
var result = from c in db.Companies 
             where c.ID == iID && !comapaniesWhereUserIsAdmin.Contains(c.ID) 
             select c;
```

Comment: thank you . i can understand your idea . This is also a good reference